# Conditioned on the expectation and covariance, is the total variation distance maximal for Gaussian distributions?

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, gaussian

I want to find two distributions $p_1, p_2$, whose [total variation distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation_distance_of_probability_measures) is the largest between all pairs of distributions whose expectations  $\mu_1, \mu_2\in \mathbb{R}^d$ and covariances $\Sigma_1, \Sigma_2\in \mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$ are fixed.

It seems like the answer should be two Gaussians with the corresponding moments, because they maximize the entropy, but I'm not sure.

Comment: The maximal variation distance between two probability measures is achieved if they are supported on disjoint sets. So I would not start looking among families of mutually absolutely continuous probability measures.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Yes you're right, the answer is obvious. I was silly. You can achieve a total variation distance approaching 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Michael's comment I realised that the answer is not two Gaussians, but rather two disjointly supported distributions. One can easily construct examples where the total variation distance approaches unity for and choice of $\mu_i$ and $\Sigma_i$.